# Ng2-charts Angular 2 - Atualização é realizada no gráfico, porém, com dados vazios

Tags: angular, front-end, chartjs

Estou tentando atualizar um gráfico utilizando ng2-chartjs no Angular 2 (especificamente Angular 7.2.0). Ao atualizar, o gráfico é redimensionado, porém, a linha do gráfico não é desenhada. Para ficar mais claro, eis o que acontece quando recebo novos dados:

[image: Aparentemente a linha não é desenhada.]

Já verifiquei os dados no console e está tudo de acordo com o que está vindo do servidor. Quando eu recarrego a página, o gráfico é desenhado normalmente, conforme início do gif.

Canvas no html (ng2-chartjs):

```
<div style="display: block;" *ngIf="lineChartData.length > 0">
          <canvas
            #chart
            baseChart
            width="800px"
            height="400px"
            [datasets]="lineChartData"
            [labels]="lineChartLabels[0]"
            [options]="lineChartOptions"
            [colors]="lineChartColors"
            [legend]="lineChartLegend"
            [chartType]="lineChartType"
          ></canvas>
        </div>
```

Eu chamo essa função a cada 5 segundos, utilizando `interval`, da biblioteca rxjs:

```
private loadMeasurements(serialnumber, data?) {
    this.measurementService
      .getByEquipmentSerial(serialnumber, data)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(measurements => {
        if (measurements.length > 0) {
          this.clearVariables();
          this.measurements = measurements;
          this.measurements.forEach(element => {
            this.humidityData.push(element.sensors.humidity);
            this.formatedHumidity.push(element.sensors.humidity.toFixed(2));
            this.temperature.push(element.sensors.temperature);
            this.dataLabels.push(new Date(element.date).toLocaleString());
          });
          this.averageTemperature = this.getAverageTemp(this.temperature);
          this.average = this.getAverage(this.humidityData);
          this.loadNumberOfMeasurements(serialnumber);

          this.lineChartData.length = 0;

          this.lineChartData.push(
            {
              data: this.formatedHumidity.slice(0).reverse(),
              label: "Umidade",
              backgroundColor: "rgb(102, 194, 255)",
              fill: false
            },
            {
              data: this.temperature.slice(0).reverse(),
              backgroundColor: "rgb(153, 255, 51)",
              label: "Temperatura",
              fill: false
            }
          );

          this.lineChartLabels.length = 0;
          this.lineChartLabels.push(this.dataLabels.slice(0).reverse());

          //this.chart.chart.update();
          this.formatedHumidity = [];
          this.humidityData = [];
          this.temperature = [];
        } else {
          this.timer.unsubscribe();
          this.average = "0";
          this.averageTemperature = "0";
          Swal.fire("Ops!", "Nenhuma medição registrada", "info");
        }
      });
  }
```

Eis como eu executo a função por intervalo de tempo:

```
this.timer = Observable.interval(5000).subscribe(val => {
      this.loadMeasurements(this.serialNum);
    });
```

Já tentei verificar o erro inúmeras vezes, mas sem sucesso. O console do navegador não indica nada de errado

Comment: Já tentou com setTimout?

Comment: O problema parece ser esse seu first. Ele só vai fazer uma vez e a requisição e ignorar as subsequentes.

Comment: Não utilizei o setTimeout. Verifiquei que o modo de realizar os intervalos no Angular é por "interval". Já tentei usar tbm `import { interval } from "rxjs"`, sem sucesso

Comment: @EduardoVargas tentei retirar o first(), sem sucesso também

Comment: E se você enviar a ordem de atualização no componente onde chama o grafico com o emitter e no componente do grafico você mandar preenchar os dados? Tenta ai

Comment: @adventistaam Sou novo no Angular, como eu poderia fazer isso? Meu gráfico não é um componente, decidi deixa-lo dentro do componente que renderiza o gráfico mesmo, para facilitar a atualização.

Comment: No componente onde chama o canvas

Comment: O componente que chama o canvas é o mesmo que tenta atualiza-lo